# Having Redis and Meilisearch on a EC2 instance

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, meilisearch

I am using an EC2 instance for my meilisearch and i am wondering if i could install redis on the same EC2 instance.

How do you manage to deploy a redis instance and a search instance, do you do as multiple instances or have only one instance ?

Comment: This can depend on quite a few factors e.g. size (resources) of the server, expected load, risk etc. If the server has enough resource then it would be possible, however, there is an argument in favour of having multiple (potentially) smaller servers for each "service" that you need. This way if one goes down, you're not having to rebuild everything.

Comment: @Rwd Thank you for your advice. I was unsure about the downsides when i upgrade one service upon a major release, whether it would affect my other (redis, etc) services. I understand the risk now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using an EC2 instance for my meilisearch and i am wondering if i
> could install redis on the same EC2 instance.

There's nothing stopping you from installing all the software you want on a single EC2 instance. You would only need to make sure your server has enough CPU and RAM resources available to run both services.

> How do you manage to deploy a redis instance and a search instance, do
> you do as multiple instances or have only one instance ?

This part of your question is too broad. Are you trying to minimize costs? Maximize throughput? Is this for testing, or a live production environment? Will you need fault-tolerance and automatic disaster recovery?

There is no single "best" or "correct" answer to how you run these services, it all depends on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was unsure about the downsides when i upgrade one service upon a major release, whether it would affect my other (redis, etc) services. as i mentioned in the top comment. I was thinking about launching via an autoscaling policy to cut down the enough CPU, RAM issue. I was curious how you manage to setup this multi service setup for a production environment if the case setup is for a small scale setup. But i understood it all depends on my sepcific needs as you said. Thank you once again for the great help